# Could not able to start Emulator in jenkins build

Tags: android, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins

unable to start emulator via jenkins, tried steps like waiting for emulator start for 120 seconds.

Logs are:

> ersist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_640_QVGA_android-21_armeabi-v7a -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data -no-window
>
> emulator: WARNING: Classic qemu does not support SMP. The hw.cpu.ncore option from your config file is ignored.
>   Creating filesystem with parameters:
>       Size: 69206016
>       Block size: 4096
>       Blocks per group: 32768
>       Inodes per group: 4224
>       Inode size: 256
>       Journal blocks: 1024
>       Label: 
>       Blocks: 16896
>       Block groups: 1
>       Reserved block group size: 7
>   Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
>   [android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
>   $ /home/akash/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:7133
>   error: no such device 'localhost:7133'
>   [android] Stopping Android emulator
>   $ /home/akash/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
>   Archiving artifacts
>   Finished: NOT_BUILT

Comment: I recomend you to repeat this step manually - just open cmd/terminal and paste this command. May be timeout you have set is too low - avd sometimes start too long

Comment: I think Android Emulator plugin is having bug,Since it fails all time when i select "Run on Android Emulator" option.For my localhost jenkins setup if i attach device to my laptop and perform apk installation,junit test works fine.

Comment: Possibly related: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37614